# SSL stopped working on Google Cloud Platform when machine was resized

Tags: magento, ssl, google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I'm in the middle of an SSL security certificate nightmare involving Google Cloud Compute platform, Cloud DNS and possibly Bitnami.

I am using a Magento installation on Google Cloud Compute.  It was working fine until a few days ago I thought I would change the server size.  4 processors was too many, so I thought I'd modify the machine to go down to 2, which I did from the Cloud Console.  Everything seemed fine and I went to bed.  When I woke up the next day, the url in my browser was displaying the numeric IP address for my site rather than the domain name.  It turned out that the https:// protocol was not working because, as Chrome says, there is a mismatch between the server name (now a numeric IP address) and the name listed in the SSL certificate.

I have tried everything, including restoring the machine to the 4-processor size, regenerating and reinstalling the SSL certificate.

Can someone please help me figure out where is the disconnect?

The IP address is correct, and has not changed.  But the url www.dolcemia.com no longer shows up as dolcemia.com in the browser status bar.  The culprit, allegedly, is that the server name does not match the server name in the certificate.
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMPbb.jpg)

Comment: Did you use a dynamic or static IP address? Maybe this use case requires a static IP address for the SSL certificate to match it? Have you submitted a support ticket via the Cloud Console?

Comment: I have a static IP.  And there is no provision for submitting a support ticket to Google Cloud console for an occasional issue like this without subscribing to a support plan.

Comment: That's correct, you need a support plan to file a support ticket (but I did not know whether you have a support plan or not). You need to look at the configuration of your server, it's hard to debug without having access to it. You need to look at Magento + SSL configuration and ensure that it is correct (I'm assuming you're running on a GCE VM). I would go through some of these results: https://www.google.com/search?q=magento+ssl and compare what you have in your config vs. what you expect. It's possible  you or someone else made some temporary changes, which upon rebooting, were reverted.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Misha B.  That little push was all I needed to find the solution.

The problem was an esoteric Bitnami issue.  I needed to re-specify the hostname in a Bitnami config file.  You were right.  This file must have got changed as a result of the reboot.

This was the solution, where "dolcemia.com" is my domain name:
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/bnconfig --machine_hostname dolcemia.com

Wasn't in my ssl certificate but in the host name mismatch.

[Bitnami documentation](https://docs.bitnami.com/google/faq/#update-application-configuration)

Also, in case this helps anybody,in order to force dolcemia.com to "secure" on all pages, in Magento, Configuration set Unsecure Base URL to:

https://dolcemia.com:443/

(was http://dolcemia.com:80/)

Comment: Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!